# Клиент-серверное приложение и базы данных

Tags: java, база-данных, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте! Пишу клиент-серверное приложение на Java. В процессе возник вопрос: как лучше организовать взаимодействие с базой данных?
То есть, к примеру, клиент входит в систему и отправляет на сервер логин и пароль. После успешного прохождения данной операции он продолжит взаимодействия с сервером.
Стоит ли вынести в отдельный поток службу, работающую с базой, создать очередь запросов к ней или можно для каждого клиента сделать прямое обращение к классу, работающему с базой?

Comment: Если результаты запроса нужны "здесь и сейчас", то не вижу смысла заморачиваться с отдельной службой и асинхронностью. Достаточно напрямую работать с `DBConnection`, полученном из пула перед обработкой запроса и возвращаемом в пул после обработки. Причем это касается не только `SELECT`-ов, но и всех запросов, которые должны выполняться последовательно и/или как можно оперативнее. Для запросов, которые вполне могут выполняться асинхронно (результат их работы не нужен, да и если они выполнятся через 30 секунд - не беда), можно использовать отдельный поток, дабы не тормозить обработку запроса.

Comment: @Regent спасибо)

Comment: На здоровье. Однако это только моё мнение, и непонятно насколько оно актуально для высоконагруженных систем. Жаль, что никто больше до сих пор не высказался. Надеюсь, кто-то ещё всё же ответит

Answer (score -1):

Начнем из того, что такой вопрос может иметь ответ для каждого свой, что плохо. Ну я все равно отвечу)
К бд прямого обращения быть не должно как минимум из-за читабельности. К бд должен обращаться ДАО слой, а уже методы дао слоя должен юзать СЕРВИС слой и уже к ним юзер может иметь прямой доступ, в моем случае через слой контроллера.